# Uploading a file to my PHP server using a POST and passing it to another external server

Tags: php, rest, file-upload, restful-architecture

I've found similar posts to what I want to do, but nothing exact so please excuse me if I missed it and there is already an answer here. Also, I am a C++ engineer, but new to PHP and without much experience with networking and HTTP requests.

Here is what I am hoping to do. I have a Linux server that is running PHP that hosts a restful API for clients to access. Clients have their custom authentication to access the API and they can upload files using it. I then need to take those files send them to an external server using my private authentication credentials. I can easily set that up so when I receive the POST, I create a new HTTP request to post it to my private server and then return the results back to the client.

The issue is speed. The files can be quite large so that means the client will have to wait for the file to be uploaded twice before receiving a response back. One solution I have is to immediately send a response back to the client and then have the client ping the server every x seconds to check the status of the secondary upload. This would allow me to get a response back to the client faster, but is not ideal. I was hoping there is a more advanced solution that Is there a way that I can begin the secondary upload on my server as soon as I start receiving the upload so that by the time the upload to my server is complete, the upload to the secondary server will be almost complete as well. This all has to be accomplished with POST's as well, so I don't know if that is a limiting factor in the equation.

Is something like that even possible? If so, how would you recommend doing it?

Another option might be to somehow have the client directly upload to the secondary server, but how would that be possible without giving the client my private authentication. Keep in mind that the secondary server is just a restful API that accepts posts using API key and token for authentication.

Comment: _“I was hoping there is a more advanced solution that Is there a way that I can begin the secondary upload on my server as soon as I start receiving the upload”_ – not using PHP, I think – the PHP script that is the target of the upload gets started only when the complete upload has been received.

Answer (score 0):

That is a tough one. If you had FTP access on the secondary server, we could get a bit more speed eventually.

As far as I know, you can´t start sending the secondary upload at the same time you receive the file. While the file is being uploaded, it resides in a temporary folder untill the request is finished, and only then it is moved to some accessible folder. But hey, I am not 100% sure there is no possibility at all.

The current solution seems the best to me: get the file, inform the user, upload to secondary server, inform the user if it is all complete. Communication between servers is usually quite faster, and so the secondary upload should take less time than the first.

The last option, for now, is a no no. I can´t think of a way to upload directly to the secondary server, without exposing your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Looks like I am stuck with the option of returning a result to the client when the upload is complete, then starting the secondary upload while having the client ping the main server to check it's status. I think should be fine since I am limited to PHP at the moment.

Cheers